# Python use dictionary keys as function names

Tags: python

I would like to be able to use dictionary keys as function names, but I'm not sure if it's possible. As a quick example, instead of `class().dothis(dictkey, otherstuff)`, I'd like to have an option for `class().dictkey(otherstuff)`. Here's a not working code example to give an idea of what I was thinking of.

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {'stuff':'value', 'stuff2':'value2'}

    #I know this part won't work, but it gives the general idea of what I'd like to do
    for key, value in self.dict.iteritems():
        def key():
            #do stuff
            return value

>>> testclass().stuff()
'value'
```

Obviously each key would need to be checked that it's not overriding anything important, but other than that, I'd appreciate a bit of help if it's possible to get working.

Basically, my script is to store other scripts in the headers of the Maya scene file, so you may call a command and it'll execute the matching script. It stores the scripts in text format in a dictionary, where I've done a wrapper like thing so you can input args and kwargs without much trouble, and because you can only enter and execute the scripts personally, there's virtually no danger of anything being malicious unless you do it to yourself.

The list is pickled and base64 encoded as it all needs to be in string format for the header, so each time the function is called it decodes the dictionary so you can edit or read it, so ideally I'd need the functions built each time it is called.

A couple of examples from the run function:

```
    Execute a simple line of code
    >>> SceneScript().add("MyScript", "print 5")
    >>> SceneScript().run("MyScript")
    5

    Execute a function with a return
    >>> SceneScript().add("MyScript", "def test(x): return x*5")
    >>> SceneScript().run("MyScript", "test(10)", "test('c')")
    [50, 'ccccc']

    Pass a variable to a function command
    >>> SceneScript().run("MyScript", 'test(a+b)', a=10, b=-50)
    [-200]

    Execute a function without a return
    >>> SceneScript().add("MyScript", "def test(x): print x*5")
    >>> SceneScript().run("MyScript", "test(10)", "test('c')")
    50
    ccccc
    [None, None]

    Pass a variable
    >>> SceneScript().add("MyScript", "print x")
    >>> SceneScript().run("MyScript", x=20)
    20
```

So as this question is asking, in terms of the above code, I'd like to have something like `SceneScript().MyScript( "test(10)" )`, just to make it easier to use.

Comment: What is `#do stuff` *exactly*?

Comment: Something kind of like this is possible, but how to do it and whether it's a good idea depends on some other factors. Where will the method bodies come from?

Comment: This is very easy to do, and very easy to get wrong.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'll update the post with what I'm doing it for, but it'd still be interesting to know if it's possible :)

Comment: This is possible with metaprogramming after the class was declared initially. This is not however considered as a good practice in the Python community and I would advise you against it. You can find more in-depth information here: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch09.html

Comment: Updated the post with exactly what I'm doing, and thanks for the link, I'll check it out after I try out the answers :P

Comment: Honesty you're working against your tools, no helpers from IDE, a lot of possible mistakes, not catchable by PEP/PyLint... Could you please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on problem you are trying to solve, not your idea of solution?

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to solve it, didn't even know if it possible :P   The doctest thing works fine though, just thought it'd be more concise to post that instead of the whole code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "correct" way I can think of to do this looks like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        funcs = {'funcname': 'returnvalue', ...}
        for func, ret_val in funcs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, func, self.make_function(ret_val))

    @staticmethod
    def make_function(return_value):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            # do some stuff
            return return_value
        return wrapped_function
```

This should allow you do to:

```
>>> foo = SomeClass()
>>> foo.funcname()
'returnvalue'
```

Of course the question of *why* you'd want to do something like this remains, as yet, unanswered :)

***EDIT*** per updated question:

The problem lies in the fact that you cannot safely assign the method to the function signature. I'm not sure how `SceneScript().add` works currently, but that's essentially going to have to tie into this somehow or another.

Comment: Ahh nice, thanks, it works, and I updated the post with what I'm doing :)

Comment: The `add` part is quite simple, it literally just empties the dictionary key (which contains another dictionary that currently only contains a 'script' key), and resets it to the new input before encoding it again. It got a bit long with adding the doc stuff (I'm quite new to that), but the code is here in it's current state - http://pastebin.com/EeA95t6f

Comment: One thing though, could you possibly elaborate on which way it's not safe? Does that just mean it can be sketchy at times?

Comment: @Peter from your question: "because you can only enter and execute the scripts personally, there's virtually no danger of anything being malicious unless you do it to yourself." I very much doubt the validity of that argument! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to call a function residing inside the current module through a string with its name? If so,

```
def stuff(arg):
  return 5

d = {"stuff":"value","stuff2":"value2"}
print globals()["stuff"](d["stuff"])
```

will print 5.

Comment: Thanks but it's mainly usability I'm after, instead of passing an argument as a key, I'd like to use that key to call a function :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into partial functions using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), in conjunction with `__getattribute__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 6

    def funca(self, x):
        print(self.a + x)

    def funcb(self, x):
        self.a += x
        self.funca(x)

mydict = {'funca':1, 'funcb':2}
foo = Foo()

for funcname,param in mydict.items():
    print('foo before:', foo.a, foo.b)
    print('calling', funcname)
    functools.partial(foo.__getattribute__(funcname), param)()
    print('foo after:', foo.a, foo.b)
```

Output:

```
foo before: 5 6
calling funca
6
foo after: 5 6
foo before: 5 6
calling funcb
9
foo after: 7 6
```